# Vue.js2.0 - vue reactivity confusion

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my project , i have a shoppinglists Array to get displayed. When the component is mounted, the store is populated ( it' conatins only one array for the logged customer, fetched from the API db server... wo any problem)

On dissplay, I get the following message :

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:571 [Vue warn]: Property or method "shoppinglists" is not defined on 
the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, 
either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the 
property. 
See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

The shoppinglists property is defined as computed ...

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([ { shoppinglists: 'getShoppingLists' } ])
},
```

And the store contains the shoppinglists array

STATE

```
{
 "shoppinglists":
 [{"title":"Groceries","items":[{"text":"Bananas","checked":true},
 {"text":"Apples","checked":false}],"id":1,"userId":1}],
 "isAuthenticated":true,
 "currentUserId":1
 }
```

If I insert a prop declaration in data :

```
   data: function () {
  return {
    shoppinglists: []
  }
},
```

the warning disappear, but still theres is no list displayed..

what could be wrong ?
thanks for feedback

not exactly duplicated question, but not far from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678983/vue-js-computed-property-not-updating)

Comment: have you declared `getShoppingLists` getter? if so, can you post its declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have mixed the two different options for mapGetters().
You can either write it like this:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'doneTodosCount',
      'anotherGetter',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

Which maps `this.doneTodosCount` to `this.$store.doneTodosCount` and so on.
Or you could do it this way, which is probably what you want:

```
...mapGetters({
  // map `this.doneCount` to `store.getters.doneTodosCount`
  doneCount: 'doneTodosCount'
})
```

And for your example this becomes:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({ shoppinglists: 'getShoppingLists' })
},
```

More documentation and source of the examples are at the bottom of [this article](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).

Comment: thanks @awnton , however what's teh difference between what I wrote :  

computed: {
  ...mapGetters([ { shoppinglists: 'getShoppingLists' } ])
},


and what you mentioned (second option) :
...mapGetters({
  // map `this.doneCount` to `store.getters.doneTodosCount`
  doneCount: 'doneTodosCount'
})

Comment: You are passing an array to mapGetters() instead of an object. I.e you've accidentally wrapped `{ shoppinglists: 'getShoppingLists' }` in `[` `]`. So the only difference in my update of your example is that I removed the brackets.

Comment: Woow...  I'm getting tired .. or I need to change my glasses... You're right !  better wo brackets !!